# Equivalence classes notation meaning

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

What does it mean for some element $x$ to be an element of the equivalence class $[y]$.

If I have some set $A$, and an equivalence relation, $R$, and the equivalence class is not explicitly defined, I know $A \times A$ gives me the subset $R$, does that mean for every $s \in A$, $[y] = \{ s \in A \mid (s,y)\}.$

So, isn't it already implied that $x$ is an element of $[y]$ because within $A \times A$ we have $(x,y)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking the literal meaning of $x \in [y]$? Or do you have some problem with the notation?

Comment: To be clear, are you assuming that $R=A\times A$. Because this is not always true. $R$ is just a subset of $A\times A$ which has certain properties.

Comment: What does $\{s \in A \mid (s,y)\}$ mean (note this is the cleaned up notation version of "the set of $s$ in $A$ such that $(s,y)$, which is what you originally wrote).

Comment: Yes cxx that's what I'm asking

Comment: What do you mean $A\times A$ gives you the subset $R$?   $R\subset A\times A$ but what do you mean it "gives" you $R$.   $\{3, 27, \sqrt \pi, \sqrt 2\} \subsetneq of \mathbb R$ but does $\mathbb R$ "give" me $\{3,27,\sqrt \pi, \sqrt 2\}$?  ...  And yes, for any $x$ we have $(x,y)\in A\times A$ but we don't know if $(x,y) \in R \subsetneq A\times A$.

Comment: $(x,y) \in A\times A \not \implies (x,y) \in R \subset A\times A$.  Afterall, $\pi \in \mathbb R$ does not mean that $\pi \in \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: "does that mean for every s∈A, [y]={s∈A∣(s,y)}." No.  Let $R$ be $\equiv \pmod 7$.  so $2\equiv 9 \pmod 7$ and so $2 R9$ but $2\not \equiv 5\pmod 7$ so $2 \not R 5$.  Now $[2] = \{s \in \mathbb Z| 2\equiv s \pmod 7\}$.  It's certainly true that *some* $s$ are $2\equiv s \pmod 7$ but it's obviously not true for *all* $s$.  Maybe you are confused about set notation and the $s$ *inside* the set.  $[y] = \{s\in A| s R b\}$ means that $[y]$ contains all the $s$ that *ARE* equiv to $y$ but *NONE* of the ones that are NOT!

Answer (score 1):

$[y] := \{s \in A \mid (s,y) \in R\}$. If $A = \{1,2\}$, one possible equivalence relation is $R = \{(1,1), (2,2)\}$. Then $1 \not \in [2]$, since $(1,2) \not \in R$.

Answer (score 1):

$R \subseteq A\times A$.

$a R b$ is defined as $(a,b) \in R$.

And $[b] = \{x \in A| xRb\} = \{x \in A| (x,b) \in R\}$.

It is absolutely true that for any $x\in A$ we have $(x, b) \in A\times A$ but that in *NO* way, implies $(x,b)\in R$.

.....

Consider $A = \mathbb R$ and we say $a R b$ if $a-b \in \mathbb Z$.

That means $R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2| y-x \in \mathbb Z\} = \{x,y)\in \mathbb R^2| y = x + k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Let $b = 2.5689$   What is $[b]=[2.5689]$?  Well. if $a R b$ then $a - 2.5689= k$ for some integer.  Now $b= 2 + 0.5689$ so $a - (2+0.5689) = k$ so $a = (k+2) + 0.5689$ and $k+2$ is some integer so $a$ is ... $0.5689$ plus some integer.

In other words:

$[2.5689] = \{x \in \mathbb R| x R 2.5689\} = \{x\in \mathbb R| (x,2.5689) \in R\}=$

$\{x \in \mathbb R| x - 2.5689\in \mathbb Z\} =$

$\{x \in \mathbb R| x= (k+2) + 0.5689$ where $k+2$ is some integer$\}=$

$\{m + 0.5689| m = k+2=$ some integer $\}$.

$= \{....., -2.4311, -1.4311, -0.4311, 0.5689, 1.5689, 2.5689, 3.5689,.....\}$.

......

You will note that $\pi \ne k + 0.5689$ for any integer $k$ and that $k - 2.5689\in \mathbb Z$ so $\pi \not R b$ and $(\pi, 2.5689) \not \in R$ and $\pi \not \in [2.5689]$.

But you claimed that $(\pi, 2.5689) \in A\times A$.  So how can $(\pi, 2.5689) \in A\times A$ but $(\pi, 2.5689) \not \in R$.

Well, $A\times A \not \subset R$.

It's true that $R \subset A \times A$.  But it need not be true that $A\times A \subset R$.

Comment: You have a typo in the third line, where you wrote "$[b] = \{x\in A|xRa\}$": it should be $xRb$ instead of $xRa$.

Answer (score 0):

Two elements are in the same equivalence class if they're in the same [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) given by the [fundamental theorem of equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Fundamental_theorem_of_equivalence_relations). We can also say that two things in the same equivalence class are equal under the equivilence relation, so in your example this would mean $x \equiv y$ because $x \in [y]$.